# Reading from a text file after using curl

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, stderr

I'm trying to debug a curl session but I can't seem to read the data from the file created. In the code below, file_get_contents returns false and a blank page shows up:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.php.net");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
$fh= fopen('test.txt', 'w+');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fh );
curl_exec($curl);
fclose($fh);
curl_close($curl);
echo file_get_contents("test.txt");
?>
```

however when I use the code:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("test.txt");
?>
```

the content in the text file displays just fine.

Comment: This is strange... do you mean you can't read the file immediately after closing it, but can read the same unmodified file some time later?

Comment: Please try code that fetches stuff directly to a PHP variable (rather than a file, that you are trying). Here is one such example http://davidwalsh.name/download-urls-content-php-curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` set to `TRUE` makes curl returns its output as a string, but your code is not storing that output in any variable. Try something like this:

```
$content = curl_exec($curl);
print_r($content);
```

Other problem is that `CURLOPT_STDERR` sets a location to output errors, not the actual transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have no write access to current directory, try using `/tmp/test.txt` if you're not in the safe more or whatever is the name in php.